# What are the good tutorial sites to learn rdlc reportdesigning?

Tags: asp.net, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

Any one knows  what are the good tutorials available in net to have some good idea about rdlc report designing.specially grouping,subtotal,joining,sub report, binding multiple datasets to report...like stuffs.
I dont need a tutorial like how to bind data set to report...like basics. many tutorials I have fond that only cover that steps and no go further digging.

Answer (score 0):

Report design rdlc and rlc are the same , I recommend you this book "Turley P. - Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services - 2012"

Since rdlc you must create interface for capturing the parameter and sending to RV , I used to start in here [Using report parameters in local mode](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html)